# How do I fix "/bin/sh: 2: patch: not found" and "make: *** [lib/libcurl.a] Error 127" errors?

Tags: installation, compiling, install-from-source

[curl-loader](http://curl-loader.sourceforge.net/index.html) is a traffic generator. You can generate HTTP, HTTPS, FTP etc. traffic with it.

Add to that, you can simulate multiple clients (multiple source IP addresses).

Here’s an explanation of how to install curl-loader on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit box and generate HTTP, HTTPS traffic.

```
$ uname –r
3.2.0-39-generic

$ tail -1 /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS"
```

**install curl-loader**

1. download curl-loader from http://curl-loader.sourceforge.net/
2. I downloaded `curl-loader-0.56.tar.bz2`.
3. extract

   ```
   bunzip2 curl-loader-0.56.tar.bz2
   tar xvf curl-loader-0.56.tar
   cd curl-loader-0.56/
   ```
4. build requirements

   Build it using general C development environment with bash,
   gcc (3 or 4 series), make, etc on a linux machine.

   Building pre-requirements are:

   - openssl binaries;
   - openssl development package with include files (on debian package libssl-dev);

   I have not installed libssl-dev , so I installed `libssl-dev` before compiling `curl-loader`.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
   ```
5. compile

   ```
   $ pwd
   /home/hattori/My_works/curl-loader-0.56

   $ make
   [...]
   /bin/sh: 2: patch: not found" AND "make: *** [lib/libcurl.a] Error 127
   ```

How do I proceed from this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /bin/sh: 2: patch: not found

Install `patch`:

```
sudo apt-get install patch
```

You could also install `build-essential` package to make sure you have the basic tools used for compiling.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: He needs `make` and other stuff as well. Why not advising to install `build-essential` metapackage? :)

Comment: @gertvdijk `make` is already installed, otherwise he would get a "command not found" when he tried to run `make`. But install `build-essential` is indeed a better approach.